# Javascript - How to access class methods within a return function

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck on this issue for a while. I cannot describe it accurately enough to find solutions online - apologies if it is a duplicate question.

I want to access `helloWorld()` from `module.js`:

```
export function HelperProvider() {
  return class Helper {
    constructor() {
    }
    helloWorld() {
      console.log('Hello World');
    }
  }
}
```

In another file:

```
import { HelperProvider } from 'module.js'

const helperProvider = HelperProvider;
const helper = new helperProvider();

helper.helloWorld();
```

However, I encounter the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: helper.helloWorld is not a function`

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the function `HelperProvider` to get the class.

```
const helperProvider = HelperProvider();
```

```js
function HelperProvider() {
  return class Helper {
    constructor() {
    }
    helloWorld() {
      console.log('Hello World');
    }
  }
}

const helperProvider = HelperProvider();
const helper = new helperProvider();

helper.helloWorld();
```

Comment: Thank you @iota.

Comment: @kenwilde Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using module features that's not out of the box in nodejs, if you want to use `modules` you'll need to set `type: "module"` in the `package.json` file... see [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/950146#950146)

If you wanna use node ways:

`module.js`

```
function HelperProvider() {
  return class Helper {

    constructor() {}

    helloWorld() {
      console.log("Hello World");
    }
  };
}
```

module.exports = HelperProvider;

`index.js`

```
const HelperProvider = require("./Helper");
const helperProvider = HelperProvider();
const helper = new helperProvider();

helper.helloWorld();
```